# error encountered when creating arrays from a seed array using array_map

Tags: php

I'm trying to create `$scenario['B']` and `$scenario['C']` using `$scenario['A']` as seed data.  The desired final arrays are:

```
$scenario['A'] = [  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8];
$scenario['B'] = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108];
$scenario['C'] = [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208];
```

I have tried the following but get an error message: `Notice: Undefined variable: value in test.php on line 32`.

```
$scenario['A'] = range(1, 8);
    foreach(['B' => 100, 'C' => 200] as $key => $value):
        $scenario[$key] = array_map(function($element) {return $element + $value;}, $scenario['A']);
    endforeach;
```

I have tried changing part of the array_map to be `function($element, $value)` but that results in a different error `Warning: Missing argument 2 for...`  Why can't it see $value?  How can this be modified so it works?

**This works:**

```
$scenario['A'] = range(1, 8);
foreach(['B' => 100, 'C' => 200] as $key => $value):
    $constant_array = array_fill(0, sizeof($scenario['A']), $value);
    $scenario[$key] = array_map(function($element, $constant) {return $element + $constant;}, $scenario['A'], $constant_array);
endforeach;
```

Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php "The number of parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to the array_map()".  The reason `function($element, $value)` did not work was because only 1 array was being passed to the array_map().  It is necessary to make $constant_array that is the same size as the seed array, `$scenario['A']`, so that all elements in the seed array are affected by array_map().

**But I like the answer provided by @Nigel Ren more.**

Comment: You probably need `function($element) use($value) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `use` to your function call...

```
$scenario['A'] = range(1, 8);
foreach(['B' => 100, 'C' => 200] as $key => $value):
    $scenario[$key] = array_map(function($element) use ($value) 
            {return $element + $value;}, $scenario['A']);
endforeach;
print_r($scenario['B']);
```

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101
    [1] => 102
    [2] => 103
    [3] => 104
    [4] => 105
    [5] => 106
    [6] => 107
    [7] => 108
)
```